# Comparison of Camel REST DSL to JAX-RS spec (v2.0)

Tags: apache-camel, jax-rs

We are considering the option of defining our REST interfaces using Camel REST DSL, as we are already using Camel for message routing, integration patterns and more. It seems that REST DSL covers what a standard JAX-RS implementation  can do, but I am not sure if this is 100% true. Additionally, exposing the REST interfaces through Camel has the the added value of transparently propagating all the HTTP request headers to the Camel message, which seems to be a nice feature.

Apart from the non-functional issues, like separating interface and implementation that JAX-RS can offer, which option would you choose? Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find your answer?